# Does my file system really take up 140TB?

Tags: filesystem

Okay, so I opened the properties for the file system. It had the number of items, and "totalling 140.7 TB". How do I know if this accurate? What can possibly take up so much space? How do I know what can be safely deleted? And, to make matters worse, I have zero experience coding/using the terminal. Can anyone help, please?

Edit: Thank you, everyone who responded.
The disk usage analyzer says the total capacity is less than 60 GB, with almost 50 GB free. I guess the file system properties is incorrect. Do you think it's something I should worry about?

Comment: Is this a typo or does it really say "140 *Tera*bytes"? Btw, nice username ;-)

Comment: If you do not have a 140Tb disk and the totals report it does it could also be a filesystem error. Do a filesystemcheck to fix that ;)

Answer (score 3):

Open disk usage analyzer and you can drill down into directories looking for large files. No need for terminal.

[image]

But

```
find / -type f -size +1000000000c
```

will find all files larger than 1Gb from a terminal. Add a `| more` to make it list in pages or a `> /tmp/files.txt` to make a text file containing all the files it finds.

---

> How do I know if this accurate?

Find the files that are large with above command and the results will tell you if it is. It could be a file system bug though.

```
sudo -i
touch /forcefsck
```

will force a check during the next reboot.

> What can possibly take up so much space?

Video and images can. Downloading 1 image from the latest Mars pictures from the NASA site can quickly take 1Tb ;) And the latest batch was 30 pixs. Game of Thrones all six seasons in high def is going to take up some space.

> How do I know what can be safely deleted?

That is up to you to decide. Even it is is a large file ... that in itself might not mean you want to delete it.